# ¿Como puedo obtener los valores de la base de datos para graficarlos con canvas en javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo graficar los valores una base de datos con canvas, porque estoy tratando de gráficar datos de una base de datos de Access y quiero mostrar los valores registrados en una gráfica, tengo el codigo para graficar y funciona solo con datos de un arreglo introducidos directamente en el arreglo, pero quiero tomar los valores de la base de datos y gráficarlos mediante una consulta.
Aqui esta el codigo de como lo estoy haciendo. gracias de antemano.

```
var meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre",  "Diciembre"];
    //alert('3');
    var valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    alert('1');
    var consulta = "SELECT * FROM produccion WHERE area AND fecha BETWEEN #"+fecha+"# AND #"+fechaFinal+"#";
```

Comment: Hola Micha y bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato, tienes que ser mas específico en lo que pides. [Edita](/edit) tu pregunta siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Una vez arregles tu pregunte podremos ayudarte

Comment: debes agregar el codigo de ejemplo que ha hecho!

Comment: le pongo un +1 porque ya hay varios negativos y es un usuario nuevo, con gusto hay que enseñarle cómo realizar preguntas tal cual lo está haciendo el buen @LeviArista y JackNavaRow :D

Comment: Cierto @fredyfx, ojalá nuestro amigo nos de más detalles y podremos ayudarle. También le doy +1

Comment: @Micha, ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estás utilizando para conectarte a la base de datos?

Comment: Acivex    
var cadConexion = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var tablaRecord = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    
cadConexion.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Micha Ruiz\\Desktop\\ProyectoDeCOS - Modificacion\\datos.mdb");

Comment: Todo funciona pero quiero recibir los valores de la base de datos en el arreglo e imprimirlos con un for.

Comment: Quiero tomar los datos de la base de datos y graficar con ellos.

Comment: @MichaRuiz Los datos relevantes deben agregarse a la pregunta. Los comentarios se utilizan para criticar y dar recomendaciones sobre cómo mejorar un publicación. Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar más detalles como lo que indicas en tu comentario así como una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado sobre canvas.